# convert list of multiple json files into a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, list

This how I parsed multiple json files in a single list

```
base_dir = 'jsons_final_folder/'
data_list = []
for file in os.listdir(base_dir):

    if 'json' in file:
        json_path = os.path.join(base_dir, file)
        json_data = pd.read_json(json_path, lines=True)
        data_list.append(json_data)
```

And I got a list that look like this

```
print(data_list)

output:

[                                                   0

0  {"general":{"key":"value","q":"...,                                          0

0  {"general":{"key":"value","q":"...,                                          0

0  {"general":{"key":"value","q":"...,                                          0

0  {"general":{"key":"value","q":"...,                                          0

0  {"general":{"key":"value","q":"...,                                          0

0  {"general":{"key":"value","q":"...,                                          0

0  {"general":{"key":"value","q":"...,]                                         0
```

So this is my code to convert df

```
with open("f.csv","w") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    wr.writerow(data_list)
```

But I get a df that type **pandas.core.frame.DataFrame** like this:

| {"general":{"key":"value","q":"..., | {"general":{"key":"value","q":"..., | {"general":{"key":"value","q":"..., | {"general":{"key":"value","q":"..., |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

with shape of n columns and 0 rows

What I am trying to do here is to make a df out of this list that contains only jsons with specific queries but i don't what's the problem.

I also tried to add **dilimiter**

I wanted the final shape be look like this

| json |
| --- |
| {"general":{"key":"value","q":"..., |
| {"general":{"key":"value","q":"..., |

Thank you

Comment: What *exactly* is in the files? I'm struggling to make sense of the output of `print(data_list)` (e.g. what are all the `0`'s?).

Comment: `writerow` writes a single row. You have to loop over the items in `data_list` and write each in a separate row.

Comment: I looped over the items and the output is empty

Comment: with open("out.csv","w") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    # ,delimiter="\n"
    count = 0
    for items in data_list:
        count =+1
        wr.writerows(items)
        if count == len(data_list):
            break

Comment: This is a data that came from an api and I'm also struggling why it exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I found the solution from [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5c9P1eQqMgc&t=80s)

function to return files

```
def get_files(filepath):
   all_files = []
   for root, dirs, files in os.walk(filepath):
      files = glob.glob(os.path.join(root,'*.json'))
      for f in files:
          all_files.append(os.path.abspath(f))
   return all_files


j_files = get_files("../path goes here/")
```

Here we read each file and import it into list

```
j_files_list = []
for j_file in j_files:
    with open(j_file) as doc:
        exp = json.load(doc)
        j_files_list.append(exp)
```

here we convert it into a df

```
df = pd.DataFrame(j_files_list)
```

And then save list to csv

```
df.to_csv('json_files_in_df.csv')
```

Thanks for helping out

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `df = pd.DataFrame({'json': data_list})` ?

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'json': data_list}) makes a df with this shape of - each row has 3 dots but no data

Comment: Oh, I just noticed you're using pd.read_json to read from files. That means your list is a list of dataframe. If you want JSON strings in your resulting dataframe, you could either read the files as strings, so that you have a list of strings.

Comment: execuse me but can you explain more?

Comment: Sure. You're using `pd.read_json` to populate `data_list`. Since `pd.read_json` converts JSON into a DataFrame, your `data_list` is a list of DataFrames. Instead of using `pd.read_json`, you could read the files as strings, with something like this:

  `json_file = open(os.path.join(base_dir, file), "r")`

  `data = json_file.read()`